# From PSC to real location

Tags: android, localization, cellular-network, umts, cellinfo

Using TelephonyManager.getAllCellInfo() I was able to get information about neighboring cell tower including cellid, but in case of UMTS I only get the PSC value.
Is it possible to know a location of a cell tower from its PSC and the MCC, MNC, LAC and CID of a neighbor cell tower?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, but you would have to reference a database that includes lat/long and CID. There are companies that provide this information (e.g. [OpenCellID](http://opencellid.org/)) for which there is an API available.

Otherwise, you can dig through [FCC/FAA registrations](http://wireless2.fcc.gov/UlsApp/AsrSearch/asrRegistrationSearch.jsp) if you like, which may be more accurate, however I don't think there is an API.

If you are restricted to the attributes listed in your question, then I don't think it would be possible since none of these things are directly linked to lat/long.

Answer (score 0):

The PSC field is optional into almost all apis to cell location databases out there, in most cases, only mnc, mcc, lac, cid and the radio type are required to proceed cell-base location. Check [unwiredlabs](https://unwiredlabs.com) for example.